# Detect whether the native PDF viewer in Firefox (introduced in firefox 19) is the primary PDF viewer

Tags: javascript, firefox

Firefox has introduced a native PDF viewer in Firefox 19, which works quite well. However on my website, I want to detect whether the PDF is opened in the native PDF viewer of Adobe Acrobat Plugin.

On the basis of that I want to tell the users to choose a different viewer (Adobe Acrobat).

Comment: From [this thread](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=2649203): "I think the only way to detect if it is enabled is to embed a small dummy pdf and then run some JS code to check for the PDFJS.version variable"

Comment: that makes sense for a website... What if somebody is writing a plugin that can run on all applications?

Comment: Maybe you could use navigator.plugins to find out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.plugins

Comment: the mozilla PDF viewer doesn't come as a plugin (like chrome). It is natively integrated in Mozilla and this is because the MIME type is "text\html" for a PDF file in mozilla.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was answered in another post:

[How to detect if pdf.js is *default* reader in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16187902/how-to-detect-if-pdf-js-is-default-reader-in-firefox)

The solution is considered 'brittle' by its author; meaning it could be broken by changes in future Firefox or PDF.js updates.  It is the only working solution I have found:

http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/PDFjs/

Answer (score -1):

What if we do this:

```
if(document.contentType="text\html" && window.location.href.endsWith(".pdf") > -1)
        return true; // native PDF viewer is opened
else
        return false;
```

Above Snippet is based on assumption that for a PDF file the URL will always end with .pdf. How reliable this is?

Comment: How would you get this to run when a PDF file is loaded? As a Firefox plugin like you mentioned in your comment? If you're writing a Firefox plugin you should mention that in your question. Btw string.endsWith is only available in very recent browsers.

Comment: when PDF file is loaded in FF, the content type is text\html because it isn't PDF as i mentioned in previous comments... and we can write alternative of endsWith ourself, i just wrote it for simplicity...

Comment: As long as you also check for uppercase .PDF I imagine it woulf be pretty reliable. If you try it with a PDF that doesn't have an extension, does Firefox even detect it as such? In any case, what's wrong with checking for the PDFJS.version variable as I suggested above?